# "Someone else has been using your account" -- can I see who?

Tags: office-365, hacked

In live.com and related services that use the same account I've been receiving the message

> It looks like someone else might be using your account

Now, this has happened to me before in other services like Gmail, because I have several computers and usually log in from different places. In Gmail I can check the session log to verify the IP addresses and locations of the previous sessions so that I know its a false alarm or not.

Does live.com provide such functionality?

If so, how can I access it?

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out.

Once I verified with Microsoft that the account is indeed mine, I can log in to live.com and access the "Recent Activity" menu under the Account Settings option.

This will list the different activities in the account (password reset, successful login, etc.), with IP address, device/platform, browser, date and location.

Thanks to this I have learned that in my very specific case, I might have some kind of spyware logging as myself with Internet Explorer.

Comment: Good to know. Keep in mind that a desktop program that uses an embedded web browser on Windows will generally embed IE since that's sure to be available and easy to embed.

Comment: For anyone else interested, Skype (desktop) counts as Internet Explorer, at least in a Windows platform.